# Поменять местами первую и последнюю цифры в массиве

Tags: java

Не получается поменять местами первую и последнюю цифру в массиве.

Были идеи (возможно бредовые) найти первую и последнюю из цифр

```
int posl = mas[mas.length - 1];
int perv = mas[0];
```

А вот как поменять не знаю.
Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С одной временной переменной:

```
int temp = mas[mas.length - 1];
mas[mas.length - 1] = mas[0];
mas[0] = temp;
```

Без временных переменных:

```
mas[mas.length - 1] = mas[mas.length - 1] + mas[0];
mas[0] = mas[mas.length - 1] - mas[0];
mas[mas.length - 1] = mas[mas.length - 1] - mas[0];
```

Comment: Осторожнее с вариантом без временных переменных, используйте такие решения только в случае необходимости экономии ресурсов компьютера. Код пишется в первую очередь, чтобы его было просто читать =)

Comment: Это еще опасно из-за переполнения

Answer (score 0):

```
mas[0] = posl;
mas[mas.lenght-1] = perv;
```

Так же можно обойтись одной временной переменной, или вообще без дополнительных переменных.